# Calculating the mean within clusters in r

Tags: r, average

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
text.id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
item.id <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4)
score <- c(30,30, 30, 42, 42, 42, 60,60,60,60)

data <- data.frame("id"=id,"text.id"=text.id, "item.id"=item.id, "score"=score)
> data
   id text.id item.id score
1   1       1       1    30
2   1       1       2    30
3   1       1       3    30
4   2       1       1    42
5   2       1       2    42
6   2       1       3    42
7   3       2       1    60
8   3       2       2    60
9   3       2       3    60
10  3       2       4    60
```

Each `item.id` is embedded in each `text.id`. For example, `text.id=1` has three items in it. `text.id=3` has four items in it and so on. However, the score is the same for each `text.id` across `item.id` s. What I want to do is, for each `id` (student), the score should be averaged by dividing the number of items within each text.id. 
The dataset should look like this below:

```
> data
   id text.id item.id score mean
1   1       1       1    30   10
2   1       1       2    30   10
3   1       1       3    30   10
4   2       1       1    42   13
5   2       1       2    42   13
6   2       1       3    42   13
7   3       2       1    60   15
8   3       2       2    60   15
9   3       2       3    60   15
10  3       2       4    60   15
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave` to get the `length` per id and use this to divide the `score`.

```
data$mean  <- data$score/ave(data$score, data$id, FUN=length)
data
#   id text.id item.id score mean
#1   1       1       1    30   10
#2   1       1       2    30   10
#3   1       1       3    30   10
#4   2       1       1    42   14
#5   2       1       2    42   14
#6   2       1       3    42   14
#7   3       2       1    60   15
#8   3       2       2    60   15
#9   3       2       3    60   15
#10  3       2       4    60   15
```

Udate:

```
x <- aggregate(cbind(mean=item.id) ~ text.id, data=data, FUN=function(x) {length(unique(x))})
data <- merge(data, x)
data$mean  <- data$score / data$mean
data
#   text.id id item.id score mean
#1        1  1       1    30   10
#2        1  1       2    30   10
#3        1  1       3    30   10
#4        1  2       1    42   14
#5        1  2       2    42   14
#6        1  2       3    42   14
#7        2  3       1    60   15
#8        2  3       2    60   15
#9        2  3       3    60   15
#10       2  3       4    60   15
```

Update 2:

```
x <- aggregate(cbind(mean=item.id) ~ text.id + id, data=data, FUN=function(x) {length(unique(x))})
data <- merge(data, x)
data$mean  <- data$score / data$mean
data
#   id text.id item.id score mean
#1   1       1       1    30   10
#2   1       1       2    30   10
#3   1       1       3    30   10
#4   2       1       1    42   14
#5   2       1       2    42   14
#6   2       1       3    42   14
#7   3       2       1    60   15
#8   3       2       2    60   15
#9   3       2       3    60   15
#10  3       2       4    60   15
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I needed to explain more because it was not clear. the score should be divided by the number of items in each text id. Your function seems to divide the score by total number of items for each student id. Your results are correct but for the larger dataset, that show the difference. IT is because I should have produced a better example dataset.

Comment: OH actually one more thing, while you are into it. data$mean brings all available number of items for each text.id, but some students answered lower than the total number of items in each text.id. So data$mean is not fixed across all students. Can we also handle that?

Comment: @amisos55 Maybe the update 2 is doing what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` , we can do

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%  group_by(id) %>% mutate(mean_sc = score/n())

#      id text.id item.id score mean_sc
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1       1       1    30      10
# 2     1       1       2    30      10
# 3     1       1       3    30      10
# 4     2       1       1    42      14
# 5     2       1       2    42      14
# 6     2       1       3    42      14
# 7     3       2       1    60      15
# 8     3       2       2    60      15
# 9     3       2       3    60      15
#10     3       2       4    60      15
```

and with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, mean_sc:= score/.N, by = id]
```